# «Не + ни» друг за другом

Tags: частица

Придумайте адекватное предложение, в котором частицы **не** и **ни** идут друг за другом и не упрощаются в одно.

Comment: Считаете, что здесь исполняются все желания?

Comment: Ну я забыл сказать волшебное слово - пожалуйста.

Comment: Не в вежливости дело. Прочтите в правилах сайта, каким должен быть вопрос.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask эти что ли? У меня вопрос-просьба "Помогите найти предложение в котором ...", не вижу как он противоречит правилам, какому пункту хотя бы.

Comment: Здесь разбираются в связанных с РЯ проблемах. О придумывании же в правилах нет ни слова.

Comment: Сойдемся на "Помогите привести пример предложения", те же яйца, только не поспоришь.

Comment: Помогают делающему, а тут делание и не начиналось. Начните, и вопрос сформулируется сам собой.

Comment: Здесь другая ситуация : автор вопроса заметил необычную грамматику. Уже за это ему плюс. И ему интересно, встречается ли такой вариант в художественной или разговорной речи. Поэтому я против закрытия вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сергей Лукьяненко ("Ночной дозор"):

> Вот что страшно… я начинал ее жалеть. Не мальчишку, влипшего в игры Света и Тьмы я жалел, не девушку Светлану, над которой нависло проклятие, **не ни** в чем не повинный город, который ударит этим проклятием…

Самуил Лурье ("Техника текста"):

> Допустим, какой-нибудь человек, который считается совсем неглупым, типа Чубайса, вдруг ни с того ни с сего — ну **не ни** с того ни с сего, а в специальных обстоятельствах – говорит: «Кто не любит армию – не любит Россию».

P. S. А мне вопрос показался интересным (ничего придумывать, правда, я не стала).

Comment: А мне кажется, что здесь не слишком удачное применение этого сочетания, особенно "ну не ни".  Можно посчитать стилистической погрешностью фонетического характера
 https://studopedia.ru/10_226509_literaturnoe-redaktirovanie-problema-neblagozvuchiya-osnovnie-foneticheskie-pogreshnosti-i-nedocheti.html

Comment: Отлично, первое предложение то что надо

Comment: Ну и хорошо... Поправила вторую цитату.

Answer (score 2):

А я придумала **такой текст:**

*Мне сдавать работу надо,*

*Я ответа очень жду,*

*И сдавать сегодня надо,*

*А не в будущем году!*

***Ну не ни, ну не ни!***

*Ты с ответом не тяни!*

***Не ни** завтра-послезавтра,*

*Ни в какие больше дни.*

Answer (score 0):

Еще один класс таких выражений используется при сослагательном **бы** с вопросительными местоимениями (эта конструкция называется то ли фразеологизмом, то ли союзом, но пока не вижу причин зачем её собственное название):

```
Как бы ему ни не хотелось, а придется.
Что бы ему ни не разрешали, он это делал.
```